# How to add multiple server in BungeeCord

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have BungeeCord server for 1.8. I wants to have a fallback server and a normal server. I configure the server part part of config.yml file like this:

```
servers:
  -lobby:
    motd: 'Welcome to My Server'
    address: 192.168.0.112:25565
    restricted: false
  -fallback:
    motd: 'Server is currently in Fallback mode'
    address: 192.168.0.112:25580
    restricted: false
```

Now when I run this command : `/server fallback` it tells me This server doesn't exist. I don't know what happened there, maybe there are a syntax error. Is there any way to prevent this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you restart the bungeecord service after making the change?    Bungeecord is a bit sucky in that it **does not** have an online reload that actually works reliably.

Comment: I know it's buggy, I shut down the server already but still can connect to it. Seems like it doesn't have any change after I restarted it. I even restarted my computer and even reinstalled BungeeCord, still doesn't work. Maybe I needs to change a server.

Answer (score 1):

That is not how YAML syntax works. Change it to this:

```
servers:
  lobby:
    motd: 'Welcome to My Server'
    address: 192.168.0.112:25565
    restricted: false
  fallback:
    motd: 'Server is currently in Fallback mode'
    address: 192.168.0.112:25580
    restricted: false
```

`-`is only used in lists, for example;

```
array:
  - 'string one'
  - 'string two'
```

Answer (score 0):

At the servers list you need without "-". Now with your config your servers are -lobby and -factions , so you don't need them. You can view a list of servers at /glist or /server.
This is your new config:

> servers:
>
> lobby:
>
> motd: 'Welcome to My Server'
>
> address: 192.168.0.112:25565
>
> restricted: false
>
> fallback:
>
> motd: 'Server is currently in Fallback mode'
>
> address: 192.168.0.112:25580
>
> restricted: false